# Passing String Values to a method

Tags: java

Sorry I'm getting very confused with my program in which I am trying to call a method which returns an int, but to which I want to pass to string variables. I already got the code in the method working, but now have moved it into its own method I wish to call with checkMatchesSomewhere().

I want to pass the values of the String variables secretWord, and secretGuess to the method so they can be used in the loops. But it isn't compiling. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Many thanks. I am new to programming.

```
class App
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        App app = new App();
    }
    //constructor
    public App()

    {

        //variables

        String secretWord = "berry";
        String guessword = "furry";
        secretMatches = 0;

                //Call CheckMatchesSomewhere method
        checkMatchesSomewhere(secretword, guessword); // checks number of matches somewhere in the secretWord

        // print the number of times the secretChar occurs in the string word
        System.out.println(secretMatches);

    }

    // METHOD THAT CHECKS FOR NUMBER OF MATCHES SOMEWHERE IN THE WORD

        private int checkMatchesSomewhere(String secretword, String guessword)

        {
        // variables
        String secretWord;
        String guessWord;
        int secretMatches = 0;

        //check each letter in sequence against the secretChar
        //
        //a loop which reads through 'secretWord'
        for (int j = 0; j < secretWord.length(); j++)
        {

            //the loop which goes through 'word'
            for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++)
            {
                if (guessWord.charAt(i) == secretWord.charAt(j))
                {
                    secretMatches++;

                    //break once a match is found anywhere
                    break;
                }

            } // end word for loop

        } // end secretWord for loop

        // return the number of matches somewhere
        return secretMatches;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what errors do you have? BTW, why don't you use `equals` instead of checking if all the characters equal?...

Comment: Sorry, I am getting  error: cannot find symbol
  checkMatchesSomewhere(secretword, guessword); // checks number of matches somewhere in the secretWord
                        ^
  symbol:   variable secretword
  location: class App
on the line I call the method CheckMatchesSomewhere(...)

Comment: I would highly suggest starting with a good beginner's book on Java or the tutorials from Oracle. You have a number of issues here that show you really don't have a firm grasp on the absolute basics.

Comment: When learning to code, **avoid** copying/pasting even from your own code. You should check the names of the variables you're using. Also, get used to an standard for fields, methods and variables names.

Comment: You need to mention data type for secretMatches = 0;

Comment: If I were a compiler I would explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are minimum 10 errors in your code.Some of them.

```
 secretMatches = 0;  //where is the datatype ??
```

it should be    `int  secretMatches = 0;`

Java is case sensitive.

```
String secretWord = "berry";  //you declared like this

 checkMatchesSomewhere(secretword, guessword);  //secretWord  should pass here
```

And

```
  String secretWord = null;// you have  to intialize it.
 String guessWord = null; // you have  to intialize it.
```

ANd Finally please go through [Basics of java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Comment: Yes.. and using a debugger would have helped him a lot.

Comment: That's *one* of his problems, yes.

Comment: Even its compiled successfully ,for sure you will get the exceptions run time.Cross check for Nullpointer exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare the `secretWord` and `guessWord` variables in  the `checkMatchesSomewhere` method as they are already method arguments additionally you aren't assigning the result of the method to `secretMatches` so it will always report zero matches.

EDIT: just noticed that you've used a different case for the method arguments. I'm guessing that's probably not intended.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your logic but commen sense says when arguments are passed to a method, they should be used instead of creating new ones.

You are passing arguments to checkMatchesSomewhere() but are not using them.